# Need clarification on how some options of Sql Server Isolation Level correlate with Optimistic Locking

Tags: sql-server

Just want to know if I understand Isolation Level values meaning correctly and use them properly:

1) "*ReadCommitted: Volatile data cannot be read during the transaction, but can be modified*". 
If I use ReadCommitted, I can ensure no dirty reads are done, but I have to implement my own optimistic locking mechanism, like introduce new [Version] field and check it on every update, otherwise the latest of two parallel transactions might override data w/o any error.

2) "*RepeatableRead: Volatile data can be read but not modified during the transaction.*" In this case I do not need my own optimistic locking mechanism, as SQL Server does not let second latest transaction update already updated data, right? I guess I'll get some sort of exception if it happens.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, SQL Server has rowversion (=timestamp) data type that can be used for optimistic locking for your case 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RC indeed ensures that no "dirty reads" are done (reads on uncommitted data).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336827/how-does-sql-server-readcommitted-isolation-level-really-work/30336883#30336883)

> but I have to implement my own optimistic locking mechanism

That entirely depends on what guarantees you need regarding concurrency. I can't say much here to help you because I don't know what you are planning to do.

In RR all rows read are S-locked until the end of the transaction. This prevents concurrent updates of those rows. New rows can appear, though. In case of concurrent writes to S-locked rows the writer will wait until the reader has committed.

Comment: Optimistic locking mechanism I need to implement: In case of 2 parallel transactions I just need the one committing data latest to be rejected as the data this transaction trying to commit has already been changed since the time they were fetched inside the transaction. I need to catch this situation in my code as well, to handle this situation some way in code.

Comment: RR is sufficient for that because there are no phantom rows that would require serialization. Snapshot isolation might be enough as well.